# Visual Studio 2012 is unresponsive at start with hidden error messages (two dings at start)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, azure, visual-studio-extensions

After latest update of Azure tools, Visual Studio 2012 does not work correctly. Looks like  an unresponsive application, loading project very long, menu does not work too and you can hear two dings at start (like error message boxes, but there is no visible messages). In the some cases you can see the real message about "The HDIProjectPackage did not load correctly". At the same time Visual Studio 2013 is not affected.
You can launch Visual Studio 2012 in the safe mode: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE>devenv.exe /SafeMode` and it will work well. While launching Visual Studio 2012 with logging `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE>devenv.exe /Log`, you can find in the log  `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.xml` these error messages:

```
ERROR SetSite failed for package [HDIProjectPackage]
ERROR End package load [HDIProjectPackage]
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem caused by `Microsoft Azure HDInsight Tools for Visual Studio` which is new release and possible not compatible with Visual Studio 2012, however installs into the Visual Studio  2012 and causing problems at start.

To fix this problem, uninstall `Microsoft Azure HDInsight Tools for Visual Studio` from the system.

(Just spent three days to fix it)

Comment: My VS error was visible, but was totally whack once I got past it. This fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Mine showed only a white screen - same cause, fix worked. Thanks.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. Thank you. ++

Answer (score 12):

I'm running VS 2010, 2012 and 2013 on the same box.

I had the exactly same error when I run VS 2012 on my machine after I installed the new release of `Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013) - 2.5`.

However, once I installed `Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2012) - 2.5` again, the error has disappeared.

Hence, instead of uninstalling `Microsoft Azure HDInsight Tools for Visual Studio`, just install `Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET 2.5` for both VS2012 and VS2013. That should work.

Comment: My VS 2012 was totally unresponsive. This fixed my problems, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had different symptoms but somehow ended up at this post and crea7or's solution fixed it for me by uninstalling Microsoft Azure HDInsight Tools for Visual Studio from the system.

My Visual Studio 2013 had become unresponsive and was hanging, showing "Connecting..." on the Team Explorer and "Downloading News Feeds..." on the start page. After 10-20 minutes (sometimes never) it would eventually connect through and then work fine.

Hopefully the above text will index and help others find this post and save their time.

Thanks again crea7or, I lost 3 hiours instead of 3 days!

Comment: crea7or and JustInChronicles, thank you for the answers. I had a few developers experiencing this problem. This did the trick for them. You saved us a ton of time!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling HDInsight worked for me. I stumbled upon the solution by myself because the HDInsight tools overwrote my keyboard shortcut for managing nuGet packages. It was annoying enough I uninstalled HDInsight and as a side effect Visual Studio started up fine again.