# visual studio does not run when I connect to the internet

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I've installed visual studio 2013 and updated to 4 release, but when I connect to the internet and then try to open visual studio, the pop up menu open but  visual studio does not run.

Comment: What does "the pop up menu open" mean? Can you provide a screenshot and include it in your question?

Comment: the black window when you click visual studio to open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed "Microsoft Azure HDInsight Tools for Visual Studio"?  If so, try uninstalling it.

The below thread saved me a lot of frustration (even though it says VS 2012, I had the same for VS2013 Update 4).

[Visual Studio 2012 is unresponsive at start with hidden error messages (two dings at start)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051647/visual-studio-2012-is-unresponsive-at-start-with-hidden-error-messages-two-ding/27704578#27704578)

You could also try running a repair on the install.

Or resetting the settings http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx

Or running in safe mode, maybe a plug-in is fouling it up http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx

Comment: Big Thanks all programmer.